# How did the probability change to integral in bishop's 1.78 formula

Tags: machine-learning, probability, decision-theory

[image: formula 1.78]

In the equation R is the decision region and C is the classification.

I don't understand how did he go from probability to integral!

Comment: I assume you must have some foundation on probability density function before reading these materials. The function on the second line is simply integrating a joint distribution density of x and Classification. Not sure what is the point of confusion.

Comment: the probability of a region is is the integral of its probability density function over the region https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: That said, using the same lower case p for two different function is indeed a bit confusing out of context